# PMD error: AccessorMethodGeneration when overriding some method in Lombok Builder

Tags: java, lombok, builder, pmd

I have the following class that should be built with Lombok `@Builder`:

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class Foo {
    private String myName;
    private int myAge;
    
    public static class FooBuilder {

        // I'm overriding this method to add some validation logic
        public FooBuilder myName(String myName) {
            // some simple logic to validate "myName"

            this.myName= myName;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to add some simple logic to validate `myName` field before setting it. But I don't want to do that for `myAge`. So `myAge` field's builder and the `FooBuilder` constructor will be generated by Lombok.

This makes PMD throw an error:

> Rule:AccessorMethodGeneration Priority:3 Avoid autogenerated methods
> to access private fields and methods of inner / outer classes.

Should I suppress this error or is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

The rules [AccessorClassGeneration](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_java_bestpractices.html#accessorclassgeneration) and [AccessorMethodGeneration](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_java_bestpractices.html#accessormethodgeneration) were created to help Android (!) development, when there was a limitation with the DEX format. These generated classes/methods counted towards the total classes/methods (64k) that were possible back then.

If you are not developing old Android apps, then you can probably remove these rules completely from your ruleset. E.g. today there is [Multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) possible which allows to use more than 64k methods in your app.

Also, since Java 11, the java compiler doesn't generate those accessor classes and methods anymore, see [JEP 181: Nest-Based Access Control](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/181).